# What could be the right way to test functions combined when applying Integration testing?

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, tdd, integration-testing, bdd

A function called "validateData" is tested isolated and for simplicity’s sake it just have 2 tests, but I've found myself repeating (almost) the same tests when I use this function combined into another function, example:

**src/controllers/user/createUser.js**

```js
export function validateData(data) {
  if (!data) {
    const err = new Error('data must be present');
    err.code = 400;
    throw err;
  }
  return data;
}

export async function createUser(data) {
  validateData(data);
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.create(data);
    return 'ok';
  } catch(err) {
    throw err;
  }
}

export default createUser;
```

**src/router/user/index.js**

```js
// Dependencies:
import { Router } from 'express';
import users from 'controllers/user/createUser';
import { methodNotAllowed } from 'utils/helpers';

// Helpers:
const router = Router();

router.route('/users')
  .post((req, res) => {
    createUser(req.body)
    .then(summary => res.status(201).json({ message: "created" }))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ err: err.message }));
  })
  .all(methodNotAllowed(`Use solely POST method in this action.`));
```

**test/controllers/user/createUser.test.js**

```js
import { should, expect } from 'chai';
import { validateData, createUser } from 'controllers/user/createUser';

describe('Controller', () => {

  describe('#validateData', () => {
    describe('when data is not send', () => {
      it("should return error: 'data must be present'", () => {
        (() => validateData(null))
          .should.Throw("'data' must be present")
          .with.property('code', 400);
      });
    });
    describe('when data is sent', () => {
      it("should return the same data input", () => {
        const input  = { firstName: 'Norman', lastName: 'etc' };
        const output = validateData(input);
        output.should.equal(input);
      });
    });
  });

  describe('#createUser', () => {
    describe('when data is not send', () => {
      it("should return error: 'data must be present'", async () => {
        try {
          await createUser(null)
        } catch(err) {
          err.should.include({
            code: 400, 
            message: "data must be present" 
          });
        }
      });
    });
    describe('when data is sent', () => {
      it("should return the same data input", async () => {
        const input  = { firstName: 'Norman', lastName: 'etc' };
        const output = await createUser(input);
        output.should.equal('ok');
      });
    });
  });

});
```

So if you see I'm reusing the same function "validateData" into the "createUser" function that it also can throw the same error that was tested before in the "#validateData" describe block.

Is this ok in testing software?

Also I've to reuse these 2 functions with express, so the tests for "validateData" are going to be tested 3 times.

`1. #validateData, 2. #createUser and 3. #POST /users`

I'd like to know if this is ok because to me seems ok but the tests are turning messy as I have many functions combined to get a desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to avoid testing the internals of your function validateData more than once.

If you are able to break to call change and replace your concrete function validateData with a mock that can assert that it has been called, then that should be enough to verify that validateData is called.

If you are able to replace validateData with a stub, i.e. a pre-packaged version that for a given input will return a hardcoded output, then you can use that to verify that the caller behaves properly when validateData returns a well known value for a well known input.

Finally, if you verify validateData with the same inputs, and expect the same outputs, as you used with the stub above, you can be pretty sure that it will work when put into production. At least for the cases your verified using the stub and later for validateData.

Repeating the same test in many places is messy and will create a maintenance burden.

Comment: Ok, it's not a good idea to test the same "validateData" many times and in multiple places, only once as it can be more maintainable.
Thanks for the response!.